# Universal system audio API for Windows/Mac/iOS/Android?

Tags: android, ios, windows, macos, audio

I am thinking of building an equalizer application that would apply to all system audio. Ideally I would want to have versions for each major OS/platform so settings could be shared across multiple devices that a user might have.

I don't know much about audio, so was wondering if there is any universal audio API that can be hooked into across Windows/Mac/iOS/Android to process system audio? If not, would appreciate any pointers/references to how to get started working with system audio across these platforms. Preferably in a way that minimizes the amount of platform specific code required.